# User-data script doens't launch with EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Background:

- Services used: ec2, autoscaling, s3, sqs, cloudwatch
- AMI  and Environement:  Windows 64-bit
- Network: IAM and security group attached
- Job:  Run a script which starts a program (.exe) which is loaded from S3

I have an auto scale option that launches a N number of Instances. The user data script is based on aws CLI and few commands in powershell. I was expecting the instances to execute my script upon their initialization. Note that some of the tasks before the Job is to first download the aws CLI using powershell, because the rest of the script is based on aws commands

What am I missing ? I thought the launch should start the script in user-data.

Note that this script was tested on an instance with the same configurations (VPC, Security Group, etc..)

Comment: Debug the launch via Ec2ConfigLog.txt. See http://www.systemcentercentral.com/day-44-troubleshooting-aws-user-data-scripts/.

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=106754

Comment: @jarmod  The problem, is that my script has a combination of cmd commands and powershell commands with a given order. In the documentation, they say if the user data has a combination of them, then the cmd script is run first then powershell. That doesn't work for me. Also, my user data is a .bat file, should that be encoded64