# User data bash script to start services in EC2 instance not executing

Tags: linux, bash, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm having difficulty getting certain services running within my EC2 instance. I'm using an Amazon Linux AMI, and would like to start `neo4j`, the graphical database, as a service when my instance first launches.

However, I've been having trouble getting anything start, let alone `neo4j`. I can't even get the basic [tutorial user data script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) provided by Amazon working. I copied and pasted the below code:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd
service httpd start
chkconfig httpd on
```

into the User Data section of my EC2 instance, and then started up my EC2 instance. Theoretically, since `httpd` is started, I should be able to navigate to the IP address of my instance in a browser and see the default Apache web page (I have allowed inbound HTTP at port 80 for security group settings). However, I get a `Connection refused` error.

This is confirmed when I issue the following commands after SSH-ing into my instance:

`sudo su
service httpd status`

The response is `httpd is stopped`, when clearly the user data script is supposed to start it. Amazon recommends to debug that I check `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` for error messages, but I don't see any when I inspect the log:

```
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'init-local' at Sun, 12 Nov 2017 16:41:03 +0000. Up 5.73 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'init' at Sun, 12 Nov 2017 16:41:03 +0000. Up 5.91 seconds.
ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info+++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info:  Device   Up     Address         Mask          Hw-Address    
ci-info:    lo    True   127.0.0.1     255.0.0.0            .         
ci-info:   eth0   True  172.31.7.27  255.255.240.0  0a:8c:a2:67:1f:46 
ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Route info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info:  Route    Destination     Gateway        Genmask      Interface  Flags 
ci-info:    0        0.0.0.0      172.31.0.1      0.0.0.0         eth0      UG  
ci-info:    1    169.254.169.254   0.0.0.0    255.255.255.255     eth0      UH  
ci-info:    2       172.31.0.0     0.0.0.0     255.255.240.0      eth0      U   
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.
Your public key has been saved in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
...
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
[RANDOM ART]
+----[SHA256]-----+
Generating public/private dsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.
Your public key has been saved in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
...
The key's randomart image is:
+---[DSA 1024]----+
+----[SHA256]-----+
Generating public/private ecdsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.
Your public key has been saved in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
...
The key's randomart image is:
... [RANDOMART IMAGE]
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'modules:config' at Sun, 12 Nov 2017 16:41:04 +0000. Up 6.70 seconds.
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No packages needed for security; 0 packages available
No packages marked for update
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'modules:final' at Sun, 12 Nov 2017 16:41:08 +0000. Up 10.93 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 finished at Sun, 12 Nov 2017 16:41:08 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 11.04 seconds
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'init-local' at Sun, 12 Nov 2017 17:10:45 +0000. Up 5.85 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'init' at Sun, 12 Nov 2017 17:10:46 +0000. Up 6.04 seconds.
ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info+++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info:  Device   Up     Address         Mask          Hw-Address    
ci-info:    lo    True   127.0.0.1     255.0.0.0            .         
ci-info:   eth0   True  172.31.7.27  255.255.240.0  0a:8c:a2:67:1f:46 
ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Route info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info:  Route    Destination     Gateway        Genmask      Interface  Flags 
ci-info:    0        0.0.0.0      172.31.0.1      0.0.0.0         eth0      UG  
ci-info:    1    169.254.169.254   0.0.0.0    255.255.255.255     eth0      UH  
ci-info:    2       172.31.0.0     0.0.0.0     255.255.240.0      eth0      U   
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'modules:config' at Sun, 12 Nov 2017 17:10:46 +0000. Up 6.61 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'modules:final' at Sun, 12 Nov 2017 17:10:47 +0000. Up 7.03 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 finished at Sun, 12 Nov 2017 17:10:47 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 7.11 seconds
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'init-local' at Sun, 12 Nov 2017 17:18:25 +0000. Up 5.60 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'init' at Sun, 12 Nov 2017 17:18:25 +0000. Up 5.79 seconds.
ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info+++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info:  Device   Up     Address         Mask          Hw-Address    
ci-info:    lo    True   127.0.0.1     255.0.0.0            .         
ci-info:   eth0   True  172.31.7.27  255.255.240.0  0a:8c:a2:67:1f:46 
ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Route info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info:  Route    Destination     Gateway        Genmask      Interface  Flags 
ci-info:    0        0.0.0.0      172.31.0.1      0.0.0.0         eth0      UG  
ci-info:    1    169.254.169.254   0.0.0.0    255.255.255.255     eth0      UH  
ci-info:    2       172.31.0.0     0.0.0.0     255.255.240.0      eth0      U   
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'modules:config' at Sun, 12 Nov 2017 17:18:26 +0000. Up 6.41 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'modules:final' at Sun, 12 Nov 2017 17:18:26 +0000. Up 6.84 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 finished at Sun, 12 Nov 2017 17:18:26 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 6.93 seconds
```

I looked on StackOverflow for similar posts, and found this: [user data script doesn't launch with ec2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44055897/user-data-script-doenst-launch-with-ec2-instance?rq=1). The accepted answer says that user data scripts only execute on the first boot cycle- does that mean I need to terminate my instance and launch a completely fresh instance in order to execute my script? In which case, I feel like that defeats the whole purpose of a startup script to begin with!

EDIT: I added in a few `echo` test statements to see if they were being printed out in the logs- nope!

However, I did try `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data` from my EC2 instance, and got back this output:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Testing 1"
yum update -y
echo "Testing 2"
yum install -y httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd
echo "Testing 3"
service httpd start
chkconfig httpd on
```

So it's definitely loading my user data... just not executing it.

Comment: Is that your full log? Try too add more `echo` to debug.

Comment: @BTuan That’s part of it.  But the rest of the log is pretty much the same format. I can repaste the full thing. Could you clarify what you mean when you say try to add more echo to debug?

Comment: @BTuan just posted the full log. As you can see, I can't see any error messages!

Comment: also have you enabled ports for yum install ? you can add echo "Test" in your user data section to see if user data section is being invoked or not.         #!/bin/bash
yum update -y echo "test" 
yum install -y httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd echo "starting httpd service" 
service httpd start
chkconfig httpd on

Comment: @UsmanAzhar just added in a few echos- I don't see any of them being outputted.

Comment: If there is no `echo` output in your log, that means your script didnt run during your instance startup. Keep in mind, `user-data script` just start only one time at the first bootup. You can run other instance with smaller instance type to test your script.

Comment: @BTuan When you say that the user data script just starts only one time at the first bootup, are you saying that subsequent starts / stops of the instance do not execute the script?

Comment: no! Fisrt time when you launch new instance. The next time you stop then restart instance, it will not run `user-data` again. Thats why you must launch new instance to test `user-data` script

Comment: @Yu Chen - correct. Would you want the installation process to run each time on reboot?  If you want to start a process on each reboot, then look into /etc/rc.local. Userdata only runs on the instance launch. Its purpose is to run once, to allow for one-time server configuration before the instance is put into service.

Comment: @RodrigoM Thanks. Why don't you submit this as an answer and I'll go ahead to accept it.

Comment: @YuChen - you bet, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Configuring Instances with User Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-add-user-data)

> When you specify user data, note the following:
>
> - User data is treated as opaque data: what you give is what you get
>     back. It is up to the instance to be able to interpret it.
> - User data
>     is limited to 16 KB. This limit applies to the data in raw form, not
>     base64-encoded form.
> - User data must be base64-encoded. The Amazon EC2
>     console can perform the base64 encoding for you or accept
>     base64-encoded input.
> - User data must be decoded when you retrieve it.
>     The data is decoded when you retrieve it using instance metadata and
>     the console.
> - *User data is executed only at launch. If you stop an
>     instance, modify the user data, and start the instance, the new user
>     data is not executed automatically*

Userdata only runs on the instance launch. Its purpose is to run once, to allow for one-time server configuration tasks before the instance is put into service.

Do you want the software installation process to run each time on reboot? If you want to start a process on each reboot, then look into /etc/rc.local.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered a similar problem and the solution that worked for me is described in this article: [How can I utilize user data to automatically run a script with every restart of my Amazon EC2 Linux instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/)

So, just add your own script after the `#!/bin/bash` line and put the whole block to the **Edit user data** of your EC2 instance. Basically, it will look something like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash

# This script is run after the system reboots!

# 1. Go to the project directory.
cd /home/ubuntu/my-webapp

# 2. Run docker compose to launch the app.
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
--//--
```

Here's an example of what that page looks like, and notice the unchecked box for "*Input is already base64-encoded*":

[image: Edit user data at EC2]