# How to run a command at EC2 Instance RE-boot?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I had a project where I need to run a command at EC2 reboot. I found only information about User Data but that works only at **first launch** which is not exactly what I needed. I need a command to run everytime I connect to the machine.

Comment: I'm confused - you want it to run on each boot,  or when you log in?

Comment: Well I'm actually interested in both. But initially it was at each boot @DanielFarrell

Comment: Here is a related question with the solution: [User data bash script to start services in EC2 instance not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70707927/10748367)

Answer (score 5):

You can store a shell script in this directory:

```
/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/
```

It will be automatically run after *every* boot. (This is done by `cloud-init`, which also runs User Data scripts.)

Comment: Oh that's an even better solution ! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of research, I found a very easy solution. You can simply run.

`echo "YOUR_COMMAND" >> .bashrc`

This works also if you write it in the User Data section when launching your EC2 instance so that you don't have to SSH into it after launch.

Enjoy!

Comment: Be careful with .bashrc - its executed every time bash is launched so it could execute `YOUR_COMMAND` 1 or several times at boot and will fire again for each future login.  You might want to consider cron's `@reboot` syntax to execute `YOUR_COMMAND` once at boot time. Its also possible to execute UserData on every boot, but you need to explicitly configure that, it defaults to first boot only.

Comment: Thanks @MisterSmith, I actually didn't know that. Could you elaborate on `@reboot`? Is there some doc I can check?

Comment: There are caveats depending on your distro / cron version - your best googling your setup and the words `cron @reboot` or looking at the man page for Cron on your system  to get specific guidance (from bash: `man cron`). Basically appending `@reboot YOUR_COMMAND` to a crontab should work. Caveats include cron running before some service has started (eg DNS resolution/fileshares not working etc  - you can `sleep 5 && YOUR_COMMAND` to wait 5 seconds to allow them time to start) or issues with environment variables (eg PATH or app specific env vars missing/incorrect etc)